# check if expression has free parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func

As part of a funcletizer, i wish to replace c# expressions, that do not contain parameters, with their evaluated constants:

```
double d = 100.0;

Expression<Func<double, double>> ex1 = x => -x;
Expression<Func<double>> ex2 = () => -d;

Expression result;
result = Funcletize(ex1); // should return ex1 unmodified
result = Funcletize(ex2); // should return Expression.Constant(-100.0)
```

I know I can evaluate an expression by wrapping it in a lambda expression and invoking that:

```
object result = Expression.Lambda(ex2).Compile().DynamicInvoke(); 
// result == -100
```

When the expression contains unbound parameters, as `ex1` above, this will of course fail, throwing InvalidOperationException, since I supplied no parameters. 
How can I check whether an expression contains such parameters?

My current solution involves a try{} catch(InvoalidOperationException), but that seems a very inelegant and error-prone way:

```
// this works; by catching InvalidOperationException
public static Expression Funcletize(Expression ex)
{
    try
    {
        // Compile() will throw InvalidOperationException, 
        // if the expression contains unbound parameters
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(ex).Compile(); 

        Object value = lambda.DynamicInvoke();
        return Expression.Constant(value, ex.Type);
    }
    catch  (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `-d` to `-100` is *not* a safe operation - that changes the meaning (and potential output) of the expression radically. Do you actually want to evaluate object fields? what about properties? methods? However: if you simply want to remove the expression but keep the `-d`, *that* can be done...

Comment: yes, I want to change -d to -100. I know that this may change the output, but that is intended. all properties, fields, method results should be replaced by their values. This requires all methods and properties to be strictly side-effect-free of course

Comment: I edited in more complete evaluation for parameterless cases if you are happy to assume side-effect-free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, most things are possible. There are two separate things in play here:

- removing unused parameters, by tracking which are seen in the expression
- evaluating and inlining captured variables (emphasis: this is a semantic change) - which we do by trying to recognising the field->[field->]...field-> pattern (although the code shown might actually perform false-positives here in some cases)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double d = 100;

        Expression<Func<double, double>> ex1 = x => -x;
        Expression<Func<double>> ex2 = () => -d;

        var result1 = Demungify(ex1); // (x) => -x
        var result2 = Demungify(ex2); // () => -100
    }
    public static LambdaExpression Demungify(LambdaExpression ex)
    {
        var visitor = new Demungifier();
        var newBody = visitor.Visit(ex.Body);
        var args = ex.Parameters.Where(visitor.WasSeen).ToArray();
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(newBody, args);
        if (!args.Any() && !(lambda.Body is ConstantExpression))
        {
            // evaluate that!
            object result = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(result, newBody.Type));    
        }
        return lambda;
    }
    class Demungifier : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly HashSet<ParameterExpression> parameters = new HashSet<ParameterExpression>();

        public bool WasSeen(ParameterExpression param)
        {
            return parameters.Contains(param);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            parameters.Add(node);
            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            object value;
            if(TryEvaluate(node, out value))
            {
                return Expression.Constant(value, ((FieldInfo)node.Member).FieldType);
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
        bool TryEvaluate(Expression expression, out object value)
        {
            if(expression == null)
            {
                value = null;
                return true;
            }
            if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
            {
                value = ((ConstantExpression)expression).Value;
                return true;
            }
            // captured variables are always fields, potentially of fields of fields
            // eventually terminating in a ConstantExpression that is the capture-context
            MemberExpression member;
            if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess
                && (member= (MemberExpression)expression).Member.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                object target;
                if(TryEvaluate(member.Expression, out target))
                {
                    value = ((FieldInfo)member.Member).GetValue(target);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            value = null;
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is slightly more involved than I expected it to be :) Will have to check whether I can backport ExpressionVisitor to net 3.5 or just lift the whole project to 4.0

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can cast the `Expression` to `LambdaExpression` and see if it has parameters.

```
public static Expression Funcletize(Expression ex)
{
   var l = ex as LambdaExpression;

    if (l != null && l.Parameters.Count == 0)
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(ex).Compile();
        Object value = lambda.DynamicInvoke();
        return Expression.Constant(value, ex.Type);
    }

    return ex;
}
```

Comment: That works for the 2 examples, but unfortuntelly I need something more general